# @testable import and Bridging header don't work simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have Test target for my framework project which include:

1. Obj-C tests
2. Swift tests with @testable import to test internal classes and functions
3. Some utils written in Obj-C for my tests which should be used in both 1) and 2)

Since I want to use Obj-C utils I should add Bridging header to my test target to have access from swift sources. The problem is that @testable import doesn't work with Bridging header simultaneously: as long as I don't use Bridging header I have access to all internal API from my swift test sources, but when I add Bridging header I have only access to public API.

Has anyone experienced that? Is @testable directive implemented using Bridging header which makes using both simultaneously impossible? Thoughts on how to resolve the issue?

UPDATE:
Apparently problem appears when you're importing the same framework as @testalbe in your swift code and using @import in Obj-C in your bridging header (directly or in one of included headers). I can manage my code to avoid importing framework simultaneously from Bridging header and swift, though general problem is not resolved

Comment: It's a bug in Xcode, and still present as of Xcode 10. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3801