# Cannot cast to entity class in CoreData unit tests

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, core-data

I'm creating the entity in the production code like this:

```
    let newDevice = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context) as! Device
```

Then I'm using this class in unit tests but get this runtime error on this line:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Umando.Device' (0x6080000b6570) to 'UmandoTests.Device' (0x1151ab5c0).
```

Looks like XCode assigns different class names for different modules but then this should be some obvious known issue, yet I found no solution for that so far.

UPDATE: Code for unit text context init (adapted from someone's):

```
    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle(for: type(of: self))] )!
    return managedObjectModel
}()

lazy var mockPersistantContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PersistentDeviceList", managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
    description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
    description.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false // Make it simpler in test env

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
        // Check if the data store is in memory
        precondition( description.type == NSInMemoryStoreType )

        // Check if creating container wrong
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Create an in-mem coordinator failed \(error)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()
```

Comment: what model is your context using? it looks like you are making a different model for test - you shouldn't.

Comment: No, I have included the same model in both targets. I have only one model. ;)

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel which initializer do you use to load the data model?.  Also add the mode of creation of the managed object subclass.

Comment: could you share the code where you create the context for the test.

Comment: Edited post with more code

Comment: Looks like someone found the solution here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11342, but I cannot verify it, because ..

Comment: .. Bug in Xcode ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939804/testable-import-and-bridging-header-dont-work-simultaneously